# How to bypass/exclude a port on OpenVPN client WITHOUT bypassing all incoming traffic?

Tags: openvpn, mac-osx, mac

I read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/515272#515294) beforehand, it says:

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 100
ip route add table 100 to y.y.y.y/y dev ethX
ip route add table 100 default via z.z.z.z
```

The problem is, [this will apply to all ports](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/7381/openvpn-client-connected-to-a-server-while-listening-to-ssh#answer-36662), and then I could use iptables to DROP certain connections, but that's not what I want.

I want the OpenVPN to...

- Exclude some ports, like SSH, TeamViewer, etc.
- Tunnel all other ports, not DROP them.

Client is a Mac Mini. I can change server config if needed.

Comment: Do you want to _exclude_ the connections to specific ports via VPN for them to bypass the tunnel and connect directly to the endpoint (and not via VPN)?

Comment: @Lenniey Yes. OR only tunnel certain ports, either way. Currently, my IP is still my public IP, but when I enable `Should client Internet traffic be routed through the VPN?` I can't TeamViewer (Port 5938) into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using iptables mangle. Your routing tables are fine, you just have to add some rules to ex/include the specific traffic.

In your case it would be something like this for SSH:

```
ip rule add fwmark 2 table 100
ip route flush cache
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ethX -j SNAT --to-source z.z.z.z
                                  ^                        ^
                               your public interface      your public IP
```

This will:

1. set fwmark 2 to your routing table 100
2. flush the routing cache to avoid interference
3. set mark 2 for all packets to destination port 22 (SSH)
4. SNAT all packets going out of ethX to your public IP

I don't know if you need all of this or have to turn it around, depends on which way you want to look at it (*all* traffic via OpenVPN except xxx, or *no* traffic via OpenVPN except xxx).

E.g. you don't even have to use routing tables, but it certainly is much cleaner this way, or you don't need the SNAT / masquerade etc.